# Show hide not working onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this.

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">Menu</div>
<div id="menu-wrapper">
<ul>
    <li>link item</li>
    <li>link item</li>
    <li>link item</li>
    <li>link item</li>
    <li>link item</li>
    <li>link item</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to show/hide the menu-wrapper using the following jQuery..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn-toggle-menu').click(function() {
var hidden = $('#menu-wrapper').data('hidden');
$('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
if(hidden){
    $('#menu-wrapper).animate({
        left: '0px'
    },500)
} else {
    $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
        left: '-210px'
    },500)
}
$('#menu-wrapper').data("hidden", !hidden);

});
});
```

But, somehow it is not working.. Where am I going wrong?? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/FWzAS/12/)

Comment: You should have used [**JSHINT**](http://www.jshint.com/), to check for any syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a quote here:

```
if(hidden){
    $('#menu-wrapper).animate({
```

I have added that:

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/15/)

Comment: why is my hide menu not displayed correctly? i and d are displayed in the same line??

Comment: That's because of #btn-toggle-menu width, change it to width:10px, http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/23/

Answer (score 0):

you missed quotation across id:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').animate({
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/21/)

Answer (score 0):

A missing single quote my man, http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/FWzAS/12/,

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#btn-toggle-menu').click( function() {
       var hidden = $('#menu-wrapper').data('hidden');
       $('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
       if ( hidden ) {
          $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
              left: '0px'
          },500);
       } else {
          $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
              left: '-210px'
          },500)
       }
       $('#menu-wrapper').data("hidden", !hidden);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your ' is not properly set check it out.

```
if ( hidden ) {
    $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
        left: '0px'
    },500);
} else {
    $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
        left: '-210px'
    },500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the JS fiddle,missed quotation in `$('#menu-wrapper')`

http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/19/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-toggle-menu').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('#menu-wrapper').data('hidden');
    $('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
    if(hidden)
    {
        $('#menu-wrapper').animate({left: '0px' },500)
    } 
          else {
        $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
            left: '-210px'
        },500)
    }
    $('#menu-wrapper').data("hidden", !hidden);

    });
});
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: a missed quotation in $('#menu-wrapper)

Comment: yeahh..rt...all posts came within a gap of 1 min..all of them said the same issue i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#btn-toggle-menu').click( function() {
      var menuWrapper = $('#menu-wrapper');
      var hidden = menuWrapper.data('hidden');
      $('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
      if ( hidden ) {
         menuWrapper.animate({
            left: '0px'
         },500);
      } else {
         menuWrapper.animate({
            left: '-210px'
         },500)
      }
      menuWrapper.data(menuWrapper, "hidden", !hidden); //see change in the method
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

Your code:

```
$('#menu-wrapper).animate({
   left: '0px'
},500);
```

Updated code:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').animate({
   left: '0px'
},500);
```

You just forget to add (')

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#btn-toggle-menu').click( function() {
      var hidden = $('#menu-wrapper').data('hidden');
      $('#btn-toggle-menu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
      if ( hidden ) {
         $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
            left: '25px'
         },500);
      } else {
         $('#menu-wrapper').animate({
            left: '-210px'
         },500);
      }
      $('#menu-wrapper').data("hidden", !hidden);
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/22/